# What does it happen when we initialize a string that is bigger than the size of the array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, matrix, memory

Let us suppose the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char chars[4][4]
    {
        "@@@@",
        "@G#@",
        "@##@",
        "@@@@"
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The variable chars is a matrix of 4X4. When I'm initializing the strings in each row with 4 chars. However, strings have always a '\0' at the end. Right?

What does happen in this context in which we are not ensuring space in the matrix for storing the '\0'? In the initialization, these characters are being stored in some memory space outside the matrix or they are not being stored at all?

I mean...Th last piece of code is equivalent to this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char chars[4][4]
    {
        '@','@','@','@',
        '@','G','#','@',
        '@','#','#','@',
        '@','@','@','@'
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Or this question is dependent on the implementation and architecture?

Comment: "When I'm initializing the strings in each row with 4 chars" --> `chars[0], chars[1], ...` are not _strings_ as they each lack a _null character_.

Comment: ... which emphasizes that C strings are not a data type, but rather one particular kind of value that an array of `char` can have.  Somewhat like primes are not a data type, but rather a particular kind of value that an `int` can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean...Th last piece of code is equivalent to this one?

Yes

> Or this question is dependent on the implementation and architecture?

No

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both the piece of code are equivalent.

From C11 Standard#6.7.9p14 (Initialization) *[Emphasis added]*

> 14 An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

`char [4]` type does not have room for terminating null character for the initializer `"@@@@"`. The first `4` bytes of `"@@@@"` initializer will initialize the `4` elements of the array `char` array which is same as `char arr[4] = {'@','@','@','@'};`.

*>> Or this question is dependent on the implementation and architecture?*

No, it has nothing to do with any architecture. Language standards clearly states the behavior.